# Route.post() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined] while using Passport Authentication

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, passport.js

```
var authenticate = require('../authenticate');
const dishRouter = express.Router();

dishRouter.use(bodyParser.json());

dishRouter.route('/')
.get((req,res,next) => {
    Dishes.find({})
    .then((dishes) => {
        res.statusCode = 200;
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.json(dishes);
    }, (err) => next(err))
    .catch((err) => next(err));
})
.post(authenticate.verifyUser, (req, res, next) => {
    Dishes.create(req.body)
    .then((dish) => {
        console.log('Dish Created ', dish);
        res.statusCode = 200;
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.json(dish);
    }, (err) => next(err))
    .catch((err) => next(err));
})
```

Getting error at **.post()** function. I'm using **authenticate.verifyUser** to authenticate the user using Passport-jwt.[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJIrA.png)

Comment: Could you post `authenticate.js` code?

Comment: As @macborowy said, please post the `authenticate` code. From what I can tell with the limited code you posted, `authenticate.verifyUser` could be a function so you might want to do `authenticate.verifyUser()` But, as I said, I have not seen the `authenticate` code. Good luck!

Comment: Solved! It was just a version issue. After updating the express it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! It was just a version issue. After updating the express it worked!